# How to fix a flat DIV(popup) when scrolling down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I checked this page,http://demo.arscode.pro/ninja-popups/popups-library/?pid=337#p61 when scrolling down the page, the Popup is always also scroll down and fixed in the center of the window, how to do this effect? Is there any jquery plugin can do that?

I have already searched on google, but maybe my keywords is not extact,so that I haven't found any good solution.

Thanks

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/ninja-popups-for-wordpress/3476479

Comment: I know this plugin, but I just want to know how to fix the DIV always in the center of screen, even if scrolling down the page.